# Anchor tag jump functionality not working with dynamic content using TinyMCE

Tags: angularjs, tinymce-4

I am using TinyMCE editor to manage the contents in a CMS application which on publishing gets displayed in another angularjs SPA application. The data is saved in the backend sql server database.

The content has some dynamic data with hyperlinks in the bullets at the beginning of the statement which on clicking should go to the individual sections of the statement.

For example:

- Test 1
- Test 2

Test 1
....

Test 2
....

I tried to handle it using the anchor tag for each of the bullet points with the below markup:

```
<ul style="padding-left: 80px; color: #00ccff;">
    <li><a href="#test1"><strong><span style="color: #00ccff;"> Test 1</span></strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#test2"><strong><span style="color: #00ccff;"> Test 2</span></strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#test3"><strong><span style="color: #00ccff;"> Test 3</span></strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#test4"><strong><span style="color: #00ccff;"> Test 4</span></strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#test5"><strong><span style="color: #00ccff;"> Test 5</span></strong></a></li>
    <li><a href="#test6"><strong><span style="color: #00ccff;"> Test 6</span></strong></a></li>
</ul>

<h3 id="test1">Test 1</h3>
<h3 id="test2">Test 2</h3>
<h3 id="test3">Test 3</h3>
<h3 id="test4">Test 4</h3>
<h3 id="test5">Test 5</h3>
<h3 id="test6">Test 6</h3>
```

The page renders and on clicking the first bullet point with text: Test 1 , it jumps to location with h3 tag having text Test 1. With this change the url gets appended with #test1.
On subsequent clicks the jump functionality never works.
Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: I think you need to use [`$anchorScroll`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll). A `#`, in your case, is possibly used as a hash-bang, for routing

Comment: I tried it based on the link: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/anchorscroll-service-in-angularjs/ but it did not work for me.

Comment: I tried this snippet: <ul style="padding-left: 80px; color: #00ccff;">
    <li><a href="" ng-click="$location.hash('test1');$anchorScroll();"><strong><span style="color: #00ccff;"> Test 1</span></strong></a></li>
</ul>
<h3 id="test1">Test 1</h3> But it did not work for me. Can you please help me with some code sample.

Comment: that's not how you do this. You are supposed to call a function within a controller that uses your code with scrolling. E.g. `ng-click="scrollTo('test1')"`

Comment: All the content you see is dynamic and saved in database and managed through the TinyMCE editor. Can you please help with some code example here.

Comment: nobody will write the code for you. You need to attempt to do it yourself and when you can't, ask a question about why it doesn't work. Of course this requires you to do some research on your own first (_or it will be flagged_)